# What's the equvalent to .Net ArrayList mutable type in Scala 2.8?

Tags: list, scala, types

What type in Scala 2.8 can I use to store a list of values? In C# I'd use ArrayList.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you want an `ArrayBuffer`.  In general, in Scala, a *buffer* is a resizable, mutable, linear collection of data.  In addition to `ArrayBuffer`, a `ListBuffer` works like a C# or Java mutable list--and, in fact, `JListWrapper` wraps Java's `List` and works basically the same way.

A good source of documentation for the collections classes is the [Collections API document](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html).  It describes the implementations in detail and suggests common use cases.

Comment: @rex-kerr would you be so kind to explain what are the most important differences between ArrayBuffer and ListBuffer, and why should I use one of them rather than another? Your "works like a C#" says me I'd better use ListBuffer (as I came to Scala 2.8 right from C# (because I've moved to Linux)), but everyone else says I need ArrayBuffer, so I am still confused about this.

Comment: @rex-kerr thanks a lot. I hope someday documentation is going to be such descriptive.

Comment: @Ivan - The Collections API document has all that information, and it's fairly easy to find (though it requires one to know enough about data structures to understand the differences between a doubly linked list and an array).  Just look under "mutable collections" and "performance".  The Scaladocs don't give as much information, however.

Answer (score 4):

You use [ArrayBuffer](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`ArrayBuffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.4/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html).

You can see other mutable collections here: [`scala.collections.mutable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.4/scala/collection/mutable$package.html)

Comment: I've seen that list, but it features not very informative descriptions :-(

Comment: @Ivan If you click on the links, they will take you to a page with more informative descriptions ;-)

Comment: I mean those pages with "more informative descriptions" have still not very informative descriptions.